# Reusing Android views in a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-linearlayout

I'm making sort of a news feed, that is displayed below a static menu. To avoid the news feed from being scrolled in the tiny bit of space that's left after the menu, I wanted to scroll both the menu and the newsfeed at the same time.

Now I'm realizing this with a LinearLayout, so it doesn't scroll itself like the listview. But my question is, is using a LinearLayout, which from what I know doesn't reuse views like a listView, bad practice? How likely am I to get into memory issues, since the news feed can have A LOT of views, and they all contain images.

Many thanks!

Comment: why dont you use a listview with a header?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a pretty good chance for you to get an `OutOfmemmoryexception` in no time with this approach,If you want to go with re-using the views

I suggest you should go with the new `RecyclerView`s in Android,
[Go here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465) for a  tutorial on recycler views

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this qualifies to be an answer. But if you are using a `LinearLayout` with a header view and a `ListView` inside it, then there are no issues. Since the main worry you have is the news feed which would be recycled by the `ListView`. Neglecting to use view recycling is asking for trouble, and will likely break after 50 or so (Android hates images).

As for the header that must disappear. I would avoid putting it as the first item in a `ListView` as suggested in the comments, and rather have it static in the `LinearLayout`. And use a view translation and/or transparency to hide it. This keeps the option availible to display the header at any point, regardless of the list's scroll.